# match "id" between underscores

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I'm newbie in regexp's and have a little task. I have to write function which takes a DataFrame and returns a filtered list of columns' names:

```py
def get_ids(df: pd.DataFrame, other_id_vars: list=None) -> list:
    pattern = re.compile('_id_|_id|id_')
    list_ids = [col for col in df.columns if pattern.search(col)]
    if other_id_vars is non None:
        list_ids.extend(other_id_vars)
    return list(set(list_ids))
```

Need filter list of words with id-pattern `(\_id|\_id\_|id\_)`, like so:

```
#from this
['subs_id', 'play_id_game', 'video', 'fluid', 'id_serv'] 
#into this
['subs_id', 'play_id_game', 'id_serv']
```

but I don't like variant mentioned above. Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: There is no code and no regex in your question. [edit] and post a [mre] of what you got.#

Comment: Almost had it, `^id_|_id_|_id$` would work

Comment: What should be matched in `['subs_id', 'play_id_game', 'video', 'fluid', 'id_serv', 'id', '_id_', '_id', 'id_', 'id_id']`?

Comment: There is a simple answer `.*(?:_id|id_).*` which gets you those strings containing `id` with an underscore on either side. Seems pretty clear and it doesn't require more details or clarity. +1 thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `(?:_|^)id(?:_|$)`

Explanation:

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`_|^` - alternation, match underscore `_` or `^` - beginning of a word

`id` - match `id` literally

`_|$` - alternation, match underscore `_` or `$` - end of a word

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/is6ziL/1)

To exclude `id` from possible results try `(?:^id_|_id$|_id_)`

Comment: I like this but we don't know if OP would want `id` to remain in the array.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That would match entries that OP wants to stay in an array, so yes, OP wants entries with `id` to remain.

Comment: I'm saying that if the entry is literally `'id'` then we don't know if OP wants to keep it. OP's question seems to indicate that at least a leading or trailing underscore is required but your regex is not requiring either.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Added another option

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i want to stay all entries with `id` to remain separated from the other letters (for examle, with underscores)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Remembering to break each value of the list up and sorting the values back into a separate new list:

```
lst = ['subs_id', 'play_id_game', 'video', 'fluid', 
                                    'id_serv']

new_lst = []

for value in lst:
    formatted_val = value.split('_')
    for info in formatted_val:
        if info == 'id' or info == 'lid' or info == 'idl':
            new_lst.append(value)

print(new_lst)
```